# gridExtra 2.0.0 change title size

Tags: r, plot, gridextra

I know that gridExtra has been updated. As a result, I'm left wondering how to change title sizes. This no longer works

```
   grid.arrange(a, b, c, d,ncol=2, 
      nrow=2, main=textGrob("Title", gp=gpar(fontsize=15,font=8)))
```

That no longer works, the option for main has been changed to top but I can't figure out the textGrob features to alter the font size). Any clues? Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First, import the package `grid` with either `library()` or `require()`. 
Second, change `main` to `top` in your code.

See below:

```
library(grid)

 grid.arrange(a, b, c, d,ncol=2, 
     nrow=2, top=textGrob("Title", gp=gpar(fontsize=15,font=8)))
```

I ran into a similar issue with `gridExtra v2.0.0`, receiving the following error:

> Error in arrangeGrob(...) : could not find function "textGrob"

indicating that grid wasn't loaded as a dependency for `gridExtra`.  I resolved it by requiring or importing the library `grid` by either:`require(grid)` or `library(grid)`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 8):

Short answer: the title is now set with `top = textGrob("Title")`

Short explanation: the original argument names were all over the place ("main", "sub", "legend"(!), "left"), so this update brought more consistency (top/bottom/right/left).

Comment: it would help to know the error message. But make sure that you have loaded grid.