# Specify color of title with grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, r-grid

I'd like to change the color of the text in my title for a grid.arrange plot.

Given data like this:

```
X<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
Y<-c(2,3,6,7,8)
Y2<-c(5,6,7,8,2)
DF<-data.frame(X,Y,Y2)

g1<-ggplot(data=DF, aes(x=X,y=Y)) + geom_line(color='black')
g2<-ggplot(data=DF,aes(x=X,y=Y2)) + geom_line(color="black")

grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(g1,g2,ncol=2,top="My Title"))
```

How can I change the text color of "My Title" to a color other than black?

Comment: `top=textGrob("My Title", gp=gpar(col="blue"))`

Comment: That did the trick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the color you can use the `textGrob` function from the `grid` package and use the `gpar` argument to specify the color:

```
top=textGrob("My Title", gp=gpar(col="blue"))
```

See the `gpar` help for a list of other options such as font size, font face, etc. that can be adjusted in the same way.

I thought this question must be a duplicate, but I haven't found a question that addresses changing the color specifically, though there are some questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32280476/gridextra-2-0-0-change-title-size) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726078/changing-title-in-multiplot-ggplot2-using-grid-arrange), for example), that use other `gpar` options. If anyone is aware of a duplicate, please mark it.

Comment: My mistake with gpar was assuming the argument was "color=blue" as opposed to "col=blue". So thanks for the answer

Comment: How do you specify the text background color?

Comment: I don't think a text grob has a "background". It would probably be something like: `grid.rect(gp=gpar(fill="red"))` then `grid.text("My Title", gp=gpar(col="blue"))`.